# Android: explicit parallel code execution on multicore devices?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, parallel-processing, multicore

Is it possible to make use of Android multicore CPU? I'm thinking about something like C# `Parallel.ForEach()` ([example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720.aspx)) but if there is another approach to this, I'd also like to learn it.

My calculations can be easily divided into independent pieces. I know I can simply fire multiple Threads or AsyncTasks, but without knowing CPU abilities (1/2/4 cores - can I get such info?) it may not be as effective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android has AsyncTasks to help with multithreaded programming.  In addition, Android includes the java.util.concurrent package for all the standard Java multithreading APIs.  However, there is no equivalen to PLINQ in Java.

references:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html

You can also use `Runtime.availableProcessors()` to determine the number of processors available.

Comment: thanks, I wasn't aware of `Runtime.availableProcessors()` method!